# A property of an open ball

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $B(x, \varepsilon)=\{y: |x-y|< \varepsilon\}$.

Is it true that for every $x \in X$ and $z\in B(x, \varepsilon)$, we can find a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that if $y \in V$ then $z\in B(y, \varepsilon)$?

My problem is that can we choose a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ so that for every $y \in V$, $|y-z|< \varepsilon$? Is there such neighbourhood exist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $$\varepsilon' = \varepsilon - |x-z|$$

and let $V = B(x, \varepsilon')$.

Pick $y \in V = B(x, \varepsilon')$. Then we have $|x-y|<\varepsilon'$.

So, $|x-y|< \varepsilon - |x-z|$.

Thus, $|x-y| + |x-z| < \varepsilon$.

By triangle inequality, $|y-z| \leq |x-y| + |x-z|< \varepsilon$.

Therefore, $z \in B(y , \varepsilon)$